# Does "library/template" iphone xcode feature exist in android?

Tags: android, templates, template-engine

I am not an iPhone developer so I may not be using the right terminology. But I often receive iPhone projects which I need to port to Android.

Now, I noticed a very nice feature used by iPhone developers when developing many similar projects. They create a certain template or skeleton project where they keep files, images, and who knows what else.

Then when they want to create a similar project, they just use the same structure, files, etc.

I saw cases of creating a new project with only a few files in the new project and reusing all other files from this template project.

Again, I apologize in case I sound to lame in describing this iPhone feature, but I am not an iPhone developer and I only described what I can see (visual impression).

Does such thing exist in Android? Anyone can give me some links or tell me what to learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approximate equivalent in Android, based on your description, would be an Android library project. It allows you to keep source code and resources (images, layouts, etc.) in a common place and reuse them from project to project.

You can read more about:

- [library projects in general](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects)
- [working with library projects in Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)
- [working with library projects outside of Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)